# Error occurred during writing the data in excel .failed to read zip entry

Tags: java, selenium

I am facing a problem during writing the data in my excel file by using apache poi in selenium java.
Below are the error occurred.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to read zip entry source
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:103)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:324)
    at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)``
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:291)
    at Testing.Test.writeExcel(Test.java:34)
    at Testing.Test.main(Test.java:94)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
    at java.base/java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:245)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:159)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:195)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile$ThresholdInputStream.read(ZipSecureFile.java:213)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource$FakeZipEntry.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:132)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:56)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:100)
    ... 5 more
```

Please advice to resolve the error

Comment: please add some more information like what are you doing in code like wise...

Comment: What are the versions of Java, libraries you use?